# Given a nxn matrix $A$, show that if $A^3 = 0$ then $A-I_n$ is invertible. (Closed)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

So if we have $$A^3 = 0$$ we can say that $$A^3-I_n = -I_n$$ where $I_n$ is a n x n identity matrix. We know that to be invertible as all the columns of $I_n$ are linearly independent.
I know we can factorize that to $$(A-I_n)(A^2+A+I_n)=-I_n$$
This is where I get stuck and am not sure on how to proceed.

Comment: You are done. You've shown that it has an inverse. It's $-(A^2+A+I)$

Comment: Oh, sweet thanks!

Comment: Well, $(A-I_n)^{-1}=-A^2-A-I_n$. Where's the problem?

Comment: The problem was that I just wasn't seeing the solution, got it now!

Comment: Write the cases for minimal polynomial. Then $A-I_n$ will be invertible for all cases.

Comment: For rigor you should mention that it's also a left-inverse, though this is trivial since it follows from the same factorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another proof: suppose that $A-I_n$ is not invertible. Then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A-I_n$. Hence $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. It follows that $1=1^3$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3=0$, contradiction !

Comment: Recently started going over eigenvalues and eigenvectors so I can see how that works too! Thanks